# How to change the pointer of a variable in a struct with method implemented from interface

Tags: go

Edit: For everyone suggesting using a pointer receiver in the function: By changing the method to have a pointer receiver, the structure no longer implements the interface. I have a image at the bottom of my question showing that.

I am trying to make a setter that will mutate the pointer of a variable in a struct with a method implemented from an interface.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 1
    b := BlahImpl {id:&i}

    fmt.Println(b.ID())
    j := 2
    b.SetID(&j)

    fmt.Println(b.ID())
}

type BlahInterface interface {
    SetID(*int)
    ID() int
}

type BlahImpl struct {
    id *int
}

func (b BlahImpl) SetID(i *int) {
    b.id = i
}

func (b BlahImpl) ID() int {
    return *b.id
}
```

The current output is:

```
1
1
```

But I would like:

```
1
2
```

When I use pointer receiver I get this error because the struct is no longer implementing the interface.
[image: error]

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/oblO0tESu3

Comment: When you add the pointer receiver, the struct is no longer implementing the interface as shown in the image in the question.

Comment: you can use pointer for `b` http://play.golang.org/p/kYQS5Skic8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to be honest I do not quite get why it works this way, but this works as you want it to:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 1
    b := BlahImpl{id: &i}

    fmt.Println(b.ID())
    j := 2
    b.SetID(&j)

    fmt.Println(b.ID())
}

type BlahInterface interface {
    SetID(*int)
    ID() int
}

type BlahImpl struct {
    id *int
}

func (b *BlahImpl) SetID(i *int) {
    b.id = i
}

func (b *BlahImpl) ID() int {
    return *b.id
}
```

The difference is how the structure's methods are defined. I've added `*` before the name so reference on the structure is passed into the method. It looks like without `*` the method gets copy of the struct so the modification does not work.

Comment: I think by adding the * to the methods you are no longer implementing the interface.

Comment: The usual suspect: You cannot modify a value from within non-pointer-receiver methods. The OPs problem has nothing to do with "pointer of a variable".

Comment: It does have to do with the pointer of a variable because I can change the value of an *int by mutating the deference but I can't do that here because I need to change the reference itself.

Comment: > I think by adding the * to the methods you are no longer implementing the interface. < In fact, it does, but a bit differently - `b := BlahInterface(&BlahImpl{id: &i})` works well.

Comment: > It does have to do with the pointer of a variable because I can change the value of an *int by mutating the deference but I can't do that here because I need to change the reference itself. < Actually, you cannot change any other struct field as well. Just add normal int and try to change it: http://play.golang.org/p/7L37pHJlbJ

Comment: I'm getting this error when I add an * to the method receiver.
http://imgur.com/E0Gg46f

Comment: I added an image to the OP with this issue.